# C++ 'if' statement displays every option. Outputs show one Above the other and not one followed by the other.

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

First and foremost, I would like to say that I am a newbie when it comes to C++ so try to understand my struggle. So, for the problem. 
  I have this assignment where you have to input a 4-digit number and each of its digits has to be represented in the form of stars. The thing is we can only use what we have learned up till now so we can't use arrays etc just while,if,else and the most basic statements/loop. 
  I was wondering what is wrong with my code because when I input the 4-digit number it doesn't show the 4 digits but it shows every single number in star form one ABOVE the other. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong because I cannot understand anymore. Also do you have any suggestions how I can display the numbers chosen not one ABOVE the other, but one FOLLOWED by the other.
 Thank you guys so much in advance! Any help appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int a,b,c,d;
int a1,b1,c1,d1;

cout<<"Input 4 digit number:"<<endl;
cin>>a;

a1 = a / 1000;
b  = a % 1000; 
b1 = b / 100;
c  = b % 100;
c1 = c / 10;
d  = c % 10;
d1 = d / 1;

if (a1==1)

cout<<"\n"; 
cout<<"    **  \n";
cout<<"  ** ** \n";
cout<<" **  ** \n";
cout<<"     ** \n";
cout<<"     ** \n";
cout<<"     ** \n";
cout<<"\n";


if (a1==2)
cout<<"\n";    
cout<<"   ****  \n";
cout<<" **   ** \n";
cout<<"  *  **  \n";
cout<<"    **   \n";
cout<<"   **    \n";
cout<<"  *****  \n";
cout<<"\n";




 if (a1==3)
cout<<"\n";  
cout<<"   *****   \n";
cout<<"       *   \n";
cout<<"    ****   \n";
cout<<"       *   \n";
cout<<"   *****   \n";
cout<<"\n";


  if (a1==4)
cout<<"\n";   
cout<<"  **   **   \n";
cout<<"  **   **   \n";
cout<<"   ******   \n";
cout<<"       **   \n";
cout<<"       **   \n";
cout<<"\n";

 if (a1==5)
 cout<<"\n";    
cout<<"  ******   \n";
cout<<"  **        \n";
cout<<"  ******   \n";
cout<<"       **    \n";
cout<<"  *****      \n";
cout<<"\n";

 if (a1==6)
 cout<<"\n";    
cout<<"      ***   \n";
cout<<"     **     \n";
cout<<"    ****    \n";
cout<<"   **   **  \n";
cout<<"  **    **  \n";
cout<<"   *****    \n";
 cout<<"\n";    

 if (a1==7)
 cout<<"\n";    
cout<<"  ******    \n";
cout<<"      **    \n";
cout<<"     **     \n";
cout<<"    **      \n";
cout<<"   **       \n";
cout<<"  **        \n";
cout<<"\n";

 if (a1==8)
 cout<<"\n";    
cout<<"   ***   \n";
cout<<" **  **   \n";
cout<<"   **      \n";
cout<<"   **      \n";
cout<<" **  **   \n";
cout<<"   ***   \n";        
cout<<"\n";

if (a1==9) 
cout<<"\n"; 
cout<<" *******   \n";
cout<<" **   **   \n";
cout<<" **   **   \n";  
cout<<" *******   \n";
cout<<"      **   \n";
cout<<"      **   \n";  
cout<<"\n";



    if (b1==0)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"   ***   \n";
    cout<<"  ** **   \n";
    cout<<"  ** **   \n";       
    cout<<"  ** **   \n";       
    cout<<"  ** **   \n";
    cout<<"   ***    \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==1)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"    **  \n";
    cout<<"  ** ** \n";
    cout<<" **  ** \n";
    cout<<"     ** \n";
    cout<<"     ** \n";
    cout<<"     ** \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==2)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"   ****  \n";
    cout<<" **   ** \n";
    cout<<"  *  **  \n";
    cout<<"    **   \n";
    cout<<"   **    \n";
    cout<<"  *****  \n";
    cout<<"\n";


    if (b1==3)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"   *****   \n";
    cout<<"       *   \n";
    cout<<"    ****   \n";
    cout<<"       *   \n";
    cout<<"   *****   \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==4)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"  **   **   \n";
    cout<<"  **   **   \n";
    cout<<"   ******   \n";
    cout<<"       **   \n";
    cout<<"       **   \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==5)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"  ******   \n";
    cout<<"  **        \n";
    cout<<"  ******   \n";
    cout<<"       **    \n";
    cout<<"  *****      \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==6)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"      ***   \n";
    cout<<"     **     \n";
    cout<<"    ****    \n";
    cout<<"   **   **  \n";
    cout<<"  **    **  \n";
    cout<<"   *****    \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==7)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"  ******    \n";
    cout<<"      **    \n";
    cout<<"     **     \n";
    cout<<"    **      \n";
    cout<<"   **       \n";
    cout<<"  **        \n";
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==8)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"   ***   \n";
    cout<<" **  **   \n";
    cout<<"   **      \n";
    cout<<"   **      \n";
    cout<<" **  **   \n";
    cout<<"   ***   \n";        
    cout<<"\n";

    if (b1==9)
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<" *******   \n";
    cout<<" **   **   \n";
    cout<<" **   **   \n";  
    cout<<" *******   \n";
    cout<<"      **   \n";
    cout<<"      **   \n";
    cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==0)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"   ***   \n";
        cout<<"  ** **   \n";
        cout<<"  ** **   \n";       
        cout<<"  ** **   \n";       
        cout<<"  ** **   \n";
        cout<<"   ***    \n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==1)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"    **  \n";
        cout<<"  ** ** \n";
        cout<<" **  ** \n";
        cout<<"     ** \n";
        cout<<"     ** \n";
        cout<<"     ** \n";
        cout<<"\n";


        if (c1==2)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"   ****  \n";
        cout<<" **   ** \n";
        cout<<"  *  **  \n";
        cout<<"    **   \n";
        cout<<"   **    \n";
        cout<<"  *****  \n";
        cout<<"\n";


        if (c1==3)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"   *****   \n";
        cout<<"       *   \n";
        cout<<"    ****   \n";
        cout<<"       *   \n";
        cout<<"   *****   \n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==4)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"  **   **   \n";
        cout<<"  **   **   \n";
        cout<<"   ******   \n";
        cout<<"       **   \n";
        cout<<"       **   \n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==5)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"  ******   \n";
        cout<<"  **        \n";
        cout<<"  ******   \n";
        cout<<"       **    \n";
        cout<<"  *****      \n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==6)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"      ***   \n";
        cout<<"     **     \n";
        cout<<"    ****    \n";
        cout<<"   **   **  \n";
        cout<<"  **    **  \n";
        cout<<"   *****    \n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==7)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"  ******    \n";
        cout<<"      **    \n";
        cout<<"     **     \n";
        cout<<"    **      \n";
        cout<<"   **       \n";
        cout<<"  **        \n";
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==8)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"   ***   \n";
        cout<<" **  **   \n";
        cout<<"   **      \n";
        cout<<"   **      \n";
        cout<<" **  **   \n";   
        cout<<"   ***   \n";        
        cout<<"\n";

        if (c1==9)
        cout<<"\n"; 
        cout<<" *******   \n";
        cout<<" **   **   \n";
        cout<<" **   **   \n";  
        cout<<" *******   \n";
        cout<<"      **   \n";
        cout<<"      **   \n";              
        cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==0)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"   ***   \n";
            cout<<"  ** **   \n";
            cout<<"  ** **   \n";       
            cout<<"  ** **   \n";       
            cout<<"  ** **   \n";
            cout<<"   ***    \n";
            cout<<"\n";


            if (d1==1)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"    **  \n";
            cout<<"  ** ** \n";
            cout<<" **  ** \n";
            cout<<"     ** \n";
            cout<<"     ** \n";
            cout<<"     ** \n";
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==2)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"   ****  \n";
            cout<<" **   ** \n";
            cout<<"  *  **  \n";
            cout<<"    **   \n";
            cout<<"   **    \n";
            cout<<"  *****  \n";
            cout<<"\n"; 


            if (d1==3)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"   *****   \n";
            cout<<"       *   \n";
            cout<<"    ****   \n";
            cout<<"       *   \n";
            cout<<"   *****   \n";
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==4)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"  **   **   \n";
            cout<<"  **   **   \n";
            cout<<"   ******   \n";
            cout<<"       **   \n";
            cout<<"       **   \n";
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==5)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"  ******   \n";
            cout<<"  **        \n";
            cout<<"  ******   \n";
            cout<<"       **    \n";
            cout<<"  *****      \n";
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==6)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"      ***   \n";
            cout<<"     **     \n";
            cout<<"    ****    \n";
            cout<<"   **   **  \n";
            cout<<"  **    **  \n";
            cout<<"   *****    \n";
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==7)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"  ******    \n";
            cout<<"      **    \n";
            cout<<"     **     \n";
            cout<<"    **      \n";
            cout<<"   **       \n";
            cout<<"  **        \n";
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==8)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"   ***   \n";
            cout<<" **  **   \n";
            cout<<"   **      \n";
            cout<<"   **      \n";
            cout<<" **  **   \n";   
            cout<<"   ***   \n";        
            cout<<"\n";

            if (d1==9)
            cout<<"\n"; 
            cout<<" *******   \n";
            cout<<" **   **   \n";
            cout<<" **   **   \n";  
            cout<<" *******   \n";
            cout<<"      **   \n";
            cout<<"      **   \n";
            cout<<"\n";             
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Multi-line if statements need braces.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but can't remember what error I got let me check thank you!

Comment: yeah now that I added the brace nothing shows up when I input the 4 digit number.

Comment: Apartly from lack of braces around if blocks, you code won't work (shows vertically) since you print one digit one after another with `\n`, the newline, so it will print vertically. The printf or cout prints things line by line, you must rewrite your code, to order to merge digits asterisks line by line.

Comment: Yes thank you! I guess I really have to rewrite this messy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) allows you to conditionally execute *the following statement*. Everything after the statement that immediately follows the condition is not part of the `if` and will be executed regardless of the condition. To include multiple statements, use braces to define a [compound statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statements).

Your example preforms the following :

```
if (a1==1)
{
    // Executes if a1==1
    cout<<"\n"; 
}

// Always executes
cout<<"    **  \n";
cout<<"  ** ** \n";
cout<<" **  ** \n";
cout<<"     ** \n";
cout<<"     ** \n";
cout<<"     ** \n";
cout<<"\n";
```

You seem to be trying to preform this :

```
if (a1==1)
{
    // Executes if a1==1
    cout<<"\n"; 
    cout<<"    **  \n";
    cout<<"  ** ** \n";
    cout<<" **  ** \n";
    cout<<"     ** \n";
    cout<<"     ** \n";
    cout<<"     ** \n";
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: OH DAMN I really am a newbie. Thank you very much! Also do you have any idea how I can display the output One Followed to the right by the other and not above the other?

Comment: @adidascoder That is a lot harder than printing them in vertical order. The usual way of printing text is line by line, it's challenging to write multiple lines and then to append those lines. The most portable solution would be to generate each line and, once all of your lines have been generated, print them afterwards. Take a look at [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for storing text.

Comment: Thank you for everything! Unfortunately my professor has restricted us of using anything we haven't learned yet that's why it has become a little frustrating finishing this task.